# Why are my objects using the same variables in java?

Tags: java, arrays

This issue arose when I changed all my variables to be stored into an `int[][]`. I have an object. Every time I click a button I create a new object which has its own variables. The problem is that I decided to store all the `int` variables in an `int[][]` and now every object that I created uses the same `int[][]` grid. So I'm not sure what I may be doing wrong here.

I have tried initiating the array `int[][]` within the object constructor and outside the constructor i.e. `public static int[][] grid;` and then initiate it inside the constructor or I've initiated it within the constructor as `int[][] grid = new int[20][20]`.

Any ideas as to why this is happening? Before I had a specific `String` variable to hold that `int` value but when I changed it everything to be stored in a `int[][]` all the new objects I create use the same grid.

Comment: Is this `int[][]` field `static`, by the way? If yes, then that's the root of your problems.

Comment: Could you provide the relevant code for your class definition?

Comment: Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413898/what-does-the-static-keyword-do-in-a-class

Comment: Could you post a little bit of code and as @LuiggiMendoza said if it is static that is the problem

Comment: Yes my fields are static. Also, i can't post the code on here I tried before but it says I'm not doing it correctly so I gave up on that. I will try and remove the static insertion and get back to you guys. Thank you.

Comment: Can I see the code where the exact problem is taking place. I want to recreate the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Providing us your code would have been wonderful. Helping is so much easier when having the code you are talking about. But there was a little word in your explanation that caught my attention: static.

> I have tried initiating the array int[][] within the object constructor and outside the constructor ie. public static int[][] grid; and then initiate it inside the constructor or I've initiated it within the constructor as int[][] grid = new int[20][20].

You wrote: `public static int[][] grid`

This means you made your field static. Static fields belong to the class, but not to an instance. So all your instances share the same grid. Even if you instantiate it new in the conctructor, *there will be only one such grid.*

If you want a design, where each instance has its own grid, simply delete the `static` keyword.